# Making ontology in Protege or by Jena API library in Eclipse(Java coding)

Tags: jena, ontology, protege

Is it also possible to build an ontology with Jena API for example by Java coding in Eclipse? if yes what is the difference between making an ontology in Protege with making an ontology by Jena API in Eclipse?I am really confused about differences as I am not good in java programming.
Lots of thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you actually want to do. Are you trying to build a new ontology from scratch? Do you have an existing ontology that you want to extend by adding some data. Are you generating lots of triples using pre-existing classes and properties, based on some data you're already processing in Java?

Protege offers a GUI that allows you to create the ontology more quickly. It also gives you a graphical overview of the ontology in creation. It's sometimes hard to get the big picture even with all this help. It's a powerful tool for overall ontology authoring. Writing an entire ontology by scribbling Java code line-by line seems a gruelling task to me.

Writing plain Java code to create an onthology would be very difficult and inefficient. On top of the complexity of RDF itself, you'd need to understand the Jena API. IMO, it only makes sense if you have a well-defined ontology and you're really sure what kind of triples you want to add. In such case, using Java code to interface with some data source could save you a lot of time. Provided that you know Java itself to do it efficiently.

In your case, sticking with Protege seems the most reasonable option.

Comment: ,My task is to build an Ontology for a domain,then I need to map my Ontology to mysql Database.on top of me,and a end-user via his web application will send me a request about for example last 3 hours water consumption in Tank A,So according to this request I should query from database and send his wanted data back to him so he can take the data and make graphs for water consumption. I think my work should be a combination of Protege and Jena API,At first from scratch I should design my Ontology by Protege and then handle it by Jena API in my Java code for further processes,am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes: it's perfectly possible to create a no ontology through the Jena API and Java code.
The difference between Protege and plain old Java code is the task you need to perform: if you need to inspect an ontology or create a few concepts manually, Protege allows you to do it fairly quickly without writing code first. If you need to execute some repetitive task, on a large number of entities, or carry out something else for which Protege does not cater, then you're better off writing Java code.
This is not different from a question like: is it better to use a text editor or write a Perl script to edit text? It very much depends on the exact task at hand. Both are possible.

Comment: My task is to build an Ontology for a domain,then I need to map my Ontology to mysql Database.on top of use,and a end-user via his web application will send me a request about for example last 3 hours water consumption in Tank A,So according to this request I should query from database and send his wanted data back to him so he can take the data and make graphs for water consumption. I think my work should be a combination of Protege and Jena API,At first from scratch I should design my Ontology by Protege and then handle it by Jena API in my Java code for further processes,am I right?

Comment: May I have your opinion as well? @Ignazio

Comment: The task of exposing SQL databases as ontologies, to be interrogated through SPARQL or the Jena API, can be performed through libraries such as [D2RQ](http://d2rq.org/). I think you're right in how you wish to split your work.